# Tumblr posting api using php and curl

Tags: php, curl, tumblr

I am able to post to tumblr using the following code  from github

```js
https://github.com/sanketsa-cuelogic/Socail-Media
```

But the problem is every time i want to post i need to login and get auth from tumblr for posting.

I want that i will authorise once and save some access token , whenever i need i will post with out authorisation on my authorised account.

Comment: Usually you have to create and install an app on your social media profile with corresponding API key and secret for your personal application can properly communicate with it (like Facebook does). Did you do it?

Comment: yes i did it. @AedixRhinedale

Comment: Can you show some snippets with your implementation of this connection package (and maybe some of the posting code)?

Comment: Post it like "I want to do that stuff, so I made `that code`. This gives me `this interface`, and when I enter `that data`, it outputs me `this`, when I wanted `this`. I've tried `A`, `B` and `C` to solve it, but without success."